# C++ Как отправить двумерный массив на сервер через канал?

Tags: c++

Можно ли передать двойной массив через канал? Обычный массив я передаю так, но в случае с двумерным (MyArr[2][5000]) на сервере выводятся числа вроде -17797997
Клиент

```
HANDLE hPipe;
DWORD dwWritten;
float myArray[5000];
int i = 0;
while (i <= currentIndex) {
    myArray[i] = pointsX[i];
    i++;
}
myArray[i + 1] = -500;
hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    WriteFile(hPipe, myArray, sizeof(myArray), & dwWritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
}
return (0);
```

Сервер

```
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    float buffer[5000];
    DWORD dwRead;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,1,1024 * 16,1024 * 16,NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,NULL);
    printf("Ожидание подключения клиента\n");
    while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE) 
        {
            printf("Пользователь подключился,ожидание сообщения\n");
            while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer,sizeof(buffer), &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
            {   
                int i = 0;
                while(true) {
                    printf("X = %f       \n", buffer[i]);
                    if (buffer[i + 2] == -500)
                        break;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю можно ли передавать двумерный, но Вы можете его трансформировать в одномерный за следующей логикой:
`newArr[i + n * j] == arr[i][j]` (`n` - длина)